# Replace the default block with figure

Tags: quill

Currently, i'm buiding my rich text editor with quill and i need to create an embed for images. Before quill, i used to use redactor and i try to move to redactor. But, i already have 2 version of data from redactor before where the users is already uploaded images.

Version 1:

```html
<p>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" data-image="5bb71bdc65465e0675ba" class="img-fluid img-responsive">
</p>
```

Version 2:

```html
<figure>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" data-image="1bdc65465e0675ba1b2b" class="img-fluid img-responsive">
</figure>
```

Expected behavior:
I expect to replace the p with figure on initial parsing in quill. So, all the images have same parent figure

Actual behavior
figure is always deleted by default

I tried to register figure with blots/block/embed but i can't check and add the figure if the image doesn't have figure on its parent

Thank you